# Mysql replication of certain columns

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, replication

I've got two rails applications. One is internal and second is external client version.

In client version I have got cutted version of database. So, now I need to replicate my master MySQL db but not all data: only certain columns and certain tables.

How can I implement this job?

If there are some ruby stuff (gem for working with replication in this way), it'll be great.

Comment: [replication of differing tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-features-differing-tables.html)

Comment: ajreal - cool! this is new feature as I see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replication is typically something you do at the database layer, here is the documentation for Mysql replication:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html
That would typically replicate the entire database.

Another solution would be to have a job (perhaps written in ruby), that runs a couple of times a day and copies the desired data.

Perhaps you want to push data from the master to the slaves with as little delay as possible? Then you could make a hook on the save() method in ActiveRecord, that pushes the changes to the slave db.

Haven't looked in to it, but perhaps this is something: http://www.rubyrep.org/

Comment: yes, I've thought about dumping internal database as a delayed job or cron. But replication is more flexible solution. Problem was just in replication of certain columns. Because databases are different. But  _ajreal_ posted this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-features-differing-tables.html and this is what I need. Thanks